# Send an object in the request body using jQuery's $.load() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a POST request that I am sending up via jquery's $.load function to retrieve data to be displayed in a window.

Here is what I'm doing currently:

```
var testObject = {
        thing1: 'data1',
        thing2: 'data2',
        thing3: 'data3',
        thing4: 'data4',
        thing5: 'data5'
     }

$('#testDiv').load("controller.url", testObject);
```

While this essentially does what I need it to, I need to send the data in `testObject` via the request body, rather than the URL which is where $.load() is putting it. The request is eventually going to contain sensitive information which should not be logged or stored and the app that this functionality is being implemented within currently logs all request URLs.

I have reviewed the documentation for $.load at http://api.jquery.com/load/, but haven't been able to find anything regarding whether or not it is possible to send an object via the $.load function in the request body.

**Is it possible** using the $.load() function **to send** an object **in the request body** rather than in the request URL **?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using the `$.ajax` instead of `load` ?

```
$.ajax({ 
    type : 'POST', 
    url : 'controller.url', 
    data : testObject , 
    dataType : 'json'
}).done(function(data){
   $('#testDiv').html(data);
});
```

Comment: While this doesn't specifically answer my original question, I was able to adapt your solution to address the problem I was having.  Thank you for the suggestion